# Python, search for html tags inside a file using regex

Tags: python, html, regex

So I am doing some data analysis in which I am required to extract the page title, breadcrumb, h1 tags from hundreds of HTML and SHTML files.

Those tags are in the following format (meaning stuffs inside ,  and breadcrumb):

```
<title>Mapping a Drive: Macintosh OSX &lt; Mapping a Drive &lt; eHelp &lt; Cal Poly Pomona</title>

<p><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="breadcrumb" --><a href="../index.html">eHelp</a> &raquo; <a href="index.shtml">Mapping a Drive</a> &raquo; Mac OS X<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></p>


<h1><a name="contentstart" id="contentstart"></a><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="page_heading" --><a name="top" id="top"></a>Mapping a Drive:<span class="goldletter"> Macintosh </span>OS X  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></h1>
```

After getting those tags, I want to further extract the first part of the title `Mapping a Drive: Macintosh OSX`, last part of the breadcrumb `Mac OS X` and  the whole h1 `Mapping a Drive: Macintosh OSX`

Any idea how that can be accomplished?

Comment: Day by day, questions on parsing HTML with regex pop out. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) if you haven't yet :-)

Comment: @Tanner The problem is that Python has a comparitively weak regex implmentation, so you would likely have to run several regexes instead of just one to cover general purpose HTML of unknown makeup.  However, it is just fine for simple HTML like you show.  But tell me, what the hell is a breadcrumb?

Comment: @tchrist It is a simile for something left behind to tell you how you got there so that you don't get lost.

Comment: @chown simile ≠ metaphor

Comment: @tchrist: it's a path from the site root that tells you how you get to the page you are viewing. Something like `amazon > electronics > game console > PS3`

Comment: @tchrist I know the difference between a simile and a metaphor.  I intended to use the word simile because that is what it is.  Check it out: [what-is-the-difference-between-metaphor-and-simile](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/what-is-the-difference-between-metaphor-and-simile/)

Comment: @chown, not that we're in english.stackexchange or anything, but the source you linked to says a simile uses the word "like" or similar.  Your description of breadcrumb doesn't use anything of the kind.  It is not a simile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a real HTML parser, not a regex.  You will be happier.  `lxml.html` is highly regarded, as is `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 2):

Since most HTML is basically xml (or can easily be trimmed to be compatible with most xml parsers) I would suggest using an xml parser.  Most python HTML-specific parsers are just subclasses of an xml parser anyway.

Check out: [Python and XML](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonxml/chapter/ch01.html).

Here is a good tutorial: [Python XML Parser Tutorial](http://www.travisglines.com/web-coding/python-xml-parser-tutorial).

Also, the [xml.dom.minidom Class](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) has been super useful for me personally.

Another similar method is explained here: [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

This is a good example from the [xml.dom.minidom reference page](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html):

```
import xml.dom.minidom

document = """\
<slideshow>
<title>Demo slideshow</title>
<slide><title>Slide title</title>
<point>This is a demo</point>
<point>Of a program for processing slides</point>
</slide>

<slide><title>Another demo slide</title>
<point>It is important</point>
<point>To have more than</point>
<point>one slide</point>
</slide>
</slideshow>
"""

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(document)

def getText(nodelist):
    rc = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
    return ''.join(rc)

def handleSlideshow(slideshow):
    print "<html>"
    handleSlideshowTitle(slideshow.getElementsByTagName("title")[0])
    slides = slideshow.getElementsByTagName("slide")
    handleToc(slides)
    handleSlides(slides)
    print "</html>"

def handleSlides(slides):
    for slide in slides:
        handleSlide(slide)

def handleSlide(slide):
    handleSlideTitle(slide.getElementsByTagName("title")[0])
    handlePoints(slide.getElementsByTagName("point"))

def handleSlideshowTitle(title):
    print "<title>%s</title>" % getText(title.childNodes)

def handleSlideTitle(title):
    print "<h2>%s</h2>" % getText(title.childNodes)

def handlePoints(points):
    print "<ul>"
    for point in points:
        handlePoint(point)
    print "</ul>"

def handlePoint(point):
    print "<li>%s</li>" % getText(point.childNodes)

def handleToc(slides):
    for slide in slides:
        title = slide.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
        print "<p>%s</p>" % getText(title.childNodes)

handleSlideshow(dom)
```

If you absolutely must use regex instead of a parser, check out the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: grps = re.search(r"<([^>]+)>([^<]+)</\1>", "<abc>123</abc>")
In [3]: if grps:
In [4]:     print grps.groups()
Out[3]: ('abc', '123')
```

Comment: That does not apply to html found on the wild web, unfortunately.

Comment: Most pages these days are valid in the eyes of an xml parser.  And if they aren't, you can easily subclass an xml parser, or `"".replace()` the parts that aren't (assuming what isnt valid is static).

Answer (score 0):

html5lib is a very reliable html parser. Since your xhtml is [somewhat broken](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.csupomona.edu%2F%7Eehelp%2Fdrivemap%2Fmac.shtml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), an xml parser will reject it. Fortunately, [html5lib](https://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) has [lxml integration](http://lxml.de/dev/html5parser.html), so you can still use the full power of lxml and xpath to extract your data.